# Moving PhpStorm to a new Windows profile

Tags: windows-10, phpstorm

Due to issues with a Windows profile, I need to move PhpStorm to a new profile.

What is the best way to do that and retain all the projects, their settings, and the setting within PhpStorm?

Comment: Just copy IDE config files across: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs P.S. The path sometimes might be different if IDE installed using Toolbox app. If you have IDE Settings Sync plugin -- it may also use a bit different path for actual local settings. It can be found in `idea.log` file (Help | Show Log in Explorer)

Comment: If you have moved you projects (e.g. was `C:\Users\User1\Projects` and now it's more generic/independent `C:\projects`) then you would need to use `Open Folder` to re-open them (I mean: so they are known to IDE and can be reopened from Recent list/appear on Welcome screen). If they were stored in user-independent path already (not inside user specific profile folder) then no issues here.

Comment: I actually have to get phpStorm to start first. Before I do a re-install, I want to make sure that is the direction I should go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to give credit to Lazyone, her comment did work. Per her comments:

> Just copy IDE config files across intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/… P.S. The path sometimes might be different if IDE installed using the Toolbox app. If you have IDE Settings Sync plugin -- it may also use a bit different path for actual local settings. It can be found in idea.log file (Help | Show Log in Explorer)

> If you have moved your projects (e.g. was C:\Users\User1\Projects and now it's more generic/independent C:\projects) then you would need to use Open Folder to re-open them (I mean: so they are known to IDE and can be reopened from Recent list/appear on Welcome screen). If they were stored in the user-independent path already (not inside the user-specific profile folder) then no issues here.